# What is the best way to infinitely update my custom value in the statusline via vimscript

Tags: vim

I need to infinitely update my custom value in the statusline via vimscript. The value actually is the temperature of the current location and the name of this location. Suppose that I have vimscript function that returns this info. What is the best way to show it for the user? How can I achieve it via vimscript?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vimscript doesn't support multi-thread processing well. That's, it is not easy to do with pure vimscript.

If you want to update the temperature, I guess you don't want to update it in **real time**. How about pick some autocmd Events, if the events were triggered, you update your temperature.

There are some event was triggered quite often, like

```
CursorMoved
CursorMovedI
TextChanged
TextChangedI
...
```

But I think you don't want to put your function there. Since your temperatureFunction may send/recieve http req/res, this would take time. Doing this too often will hurt the vim performance, to disturbe user's normal editing.

I guess events like:

```
CursorHold
CursorHoldI
VimEnter
FocusGain
...
```

may help you.

```
:h event
```

to see all information of all events.

Comment: Thanks! And what is the best way to update the same value in the status line? How can I let the user to choose the position of the temperature and location info and update it?

Comment: @FrozenHeart E.g. placeholder?

Comment: @FrozenHeart I think Ingo has answered that in you another question. you can do (or you let your users do) `%{function()}` in your statusline. when you want to update the statusline, just reset the variable `&statusline` the `function()` would be the one to fetch temperature.

Comment: Ok, I'll add %{get_temperature_info()} line to the status line, but what do you mean by "just reset the variable &statusline"? How can I do it? Maybe it's better to have the global variables instead like %{temperature} and %{location_name} and update it instead?

Comment: Yep, do `%{g:temperature}`, and update that variable in the `:autocmd` periodically.

Comment: Ok, so...
I have vim.command('let g:temperature={0}'.format(temperature)) inside my GetTemperatureInfo function, set statusline+=%{g:temperature} and :autocmd SomeEvent * :call GetTemperatureInfo inside .vimrc file. Is it ok?

Comment: And where should I initialize temperature variable? At the beginning of my vimscript?